# Kotlin Runnable Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following Kotlin code, executed from the UI thread of Android:

```
Runnable {
    doSomeSuff() // Which thread will it run?
}.run()
```

On which thread will it run? The UI thread?

Comment: It runs on whichever thread you created the `Runnable`; so, the UI thread.

Comment: Yes it is the UI thread

Comment: what is the kotlin equivalent of the `crtl + alt + f` global variable declaration in java

Comment: Yeah, I didn't originally notice you'd said "executed from the UI thread". `Runnable`s have no inherent threading capabilities. They're just blocks of code to run.

Comment: Runnable will run wherever you make it run. It is an interface and it's method runs in the thread on which it was invoked from.

Comment: Rolled back to the version of the question where the code was present, it was easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Runnable` will be executed on the `Thread` it was created. In your case - UI thread. The question is - **what do you want to achieve?** There are bunch of built-in capabilities to perform background related work. I'll provide wider answer - if you explain your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

From Android Documentation:

> The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose
>   instances are intended to be executed by a thread. The class must
>   define a method of no arguments called run.
>
> This interface is designed to provide a common protocol for objects
>   that wish to execute code while they are active. For example, Runnable
>   is implemented by class Thread. Being active simply means that a
>   thread has been started and has not yet been stopped.

Why it is different from Thread:

> When an object implementing interface Runnable is used to create a
>   thread, starting the thread causes the object's run method to be
>   called in that separately executing thread.